DefaultErrorHandler to handle timeout exception for Kafka consumer
I am facing timeout exception due to various reasons with my Spring Kafka consumer. I am using the following configs to define my consumer factory with error handler.
@Bean
  public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> createListenerFactory() {
    ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
    factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory());
    factory.setCommonErrorHandler(createErrorHandler());
    return factory;
  }

private ConsumerFactory<String, String> consumerFactory() {
    Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "localhost:9092");
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, JsonDeserializer.class);
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, JsonDeserializer.class);
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.REQUEST_TIMEOUT_MS_CONFIG, 100);

    return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(props);
  }

public DefaultErrorHandler createErrorHandler() {
    BackOff fixedBackOff = new FixedBackOff(3000, 0);
    DefaultErrorHandler errorHandler = new DefaultErrorHandler((consumerRecord, exception) -> {
        log.info("Exception occured: {}", exception);
    }, fixedBackOff);
    errorHandler.addNotRetryableExceptions(UnknownTopicOrPartitionException.class,
        OffsetOutOfRangeException.class, NetworkException.class,
        SerializationException.class, DeserializationException.class);
    return errorHandler;
  }

However, despite having an error handler where I want to handle timeout effectively by sending email or whatever, in my logs I am receiving this error.
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Failed to update metadata after 60000 ms.

Questions:

Is TimeoutException a retry exception? Is it safe to retry them?

Is it possible to handle the above specified exceptions using error handler?

If yes, how to handle these exceptions using error handler (SeekToCurrentErrorHandler or DefaultErrorHandler) efficiently?

Why Kafka defines certain exception as Warning instead of Error like the following
2024-06-25T21:42:31.693+05:30  WARN 22880 --- [retry-kafka] [  test-id-0-C-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Consumer clientId=consumer-test-group-id-1, groupId=test-group-id] Error while fetching metadata with correlation id 263 : {my-topic=UNKNOWN_TOPIC_OR_PARTITION} 


I found a similar question here, but that is part of Kafka producer, my expectation is to handle these exceptions in error handler

Is it possible to have error handler for producer to retry sending the message on certain exceptions?

I tried defining the exceptions in error handler but TimeoutException or UnknownTopicOrPartitionException are not sent to error handler instead they are just logging in my console.
I am using Java 19, Kafka 3.7.0, Spring-Kafka 3.1.5
some other references I tried are 1 2

How do you ACK the messages?

Hi @PeterCsala I use RECORD acknowledgement mode and ACK CONFIG "all". Not sure if you are expecting anything else, if it is you can assume the default configs.

Sorry my bad, I posted my comment during night. I wanted to know how do you commit offsets (not the acknowledgement). Because the offsets are stored on the brokers your committing strategy might influence timeout retryability. If you do not commit the offsets between retries then yes Timeout is retryable.

properties.setProperty(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "latest")
properties.setProperty(ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG, String.valueOf(true));
properties.setProperty(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_COMMIT_INTERVAL_MS_CONFIG, String.valueOf(500));
I'm using auto commit with latest offset
